# Python formatting dictionaries within dictionary

Tags: python, azure, dictionary

I am trying to format this dictionary inside a dictionary

**The full code:**

```
for image in url_images:
    detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=image, return_face_attributes=face_attributes)
    if not detected_faces:
        await ctx.send('No faces detected in this image')

    for face in detected_faces:
        age = str(face.face_attributes.age)
        age_fin = age.split(".")
        
        gender = str(face.face_attributes.gender)
        gender_fin = gender.split(".")

        await ctx.send('Facial attributes detected:\nAge: '+ age_fin[0] + 
        '\nGender: ' + gender_fin[1] + 
        '\nEmotion: ' + str(face.face_attributes.emotion))
```

**The output I am getting with the code**

```
Facial attributes detected:
Gender: male
Emotion: {'additional_properties': {}, 'anger': 0.001, 'contempt': 0.002, 'disgust': 0.0, 'fear': 0.0, 'happiness': 0.542, 'neutral': 0.455, 'sadness': 0.0, 'surprise': 0.0}
```

**A formatting example of what is desired:**

```
Facial attributes detected:
Gender: male
Emotion: 0% anger, 0% contempt, 0% disgust, 0% fear, 0% happiness, 98% neutral, 0% sadness, 0% surprise
```

**What I tried:**

Error: `TypeError: 'Emotion' object is not subscriptable`. Here is a screenshot of my code with the attempted solution

[image]

```
emotions = ["anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happiness", "neutral", "sadness", "surprise"]
print('Emotion: ')
for emo in emotions:
    value = face.face_attributes.emotion[emo]
    print(f'{value} {emo},', end='')
print('\n')
```

**The API I am using**
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/#demo

Comment: Can you add a sample repsonse that you get from the API?

Comment: Can you elaborate please

Comment: I meant the value that you get from the variable `face.face_attributes`

Comment: There is a lot of extraneous information in this question.  Does it boil down to you have a dictionary: `{'additional_properties': {}, 'anger': 0.001, 'contempt': 0.002, 'disgust': 0.0, 'fear': 0.0, 'happiness': 0.542, 'neutral': 0.455, 'sadness': 0.0, 'surprise': 0.0}`, and want to format it as `Emotion: 0% anger, 0% contempt, 0% disgust, 0% fear, 0% happiness, 98% neutral, 0% sadness, 0% surprise`?

Comment: yes that is true @MarkTolonen

Comment: `{'additional_properties': {}, 'age': 53.0, 'gender': <Gender.male: 'male'>, 'smile': 1.0, 'facial_hair': <azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.FacialHair object at 0x00000162A1BCDEB0>, 'glasses': <GlassesType.no_glasses: 'noGlasses'>, 'head_pose': None, 'emotion': <azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.Emotion object at 0x00000162A1BF9070>, 'hair': None, 'makeup': None, 'occlusion': None, 'accessories': None, 'blur': None, 'exposure': None, 'noise': None}
`

This is the output I get when I simply `print(face.face_attributes)`

Comment: Isn't this the same as your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65244655/formatting-of-dictionaries

Comment: The error indicates that the value of `face.face_attributes.emotion` is not actually a dictionary, even though it prints like one. It's an instance of a class called `Emotion`.

Comment: Since `Emotion` is not a standard Python class, it's probably something defined by the API library. You'll need to check its documentation to find out how to access emotions dynamically.

Comment: It looks like the `ToRankedList()` function mentioned on that help page might return the dictionary.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models.emotion?view=azure-python

I found more info here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
import os
import json

endpoint = ''
key = ''
face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(key))
single_face_image_url = 'https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-4c22a847f7d6cb9f6d140f4927646992a7343e54da079181e641d3aae5d130bb/images/shared/cognitive-services-demos/face-detection/detection-1-thumbnail.jpg'
single_image_name = os.path.basename(single_face_image_url)
face_attributes = ['emotion']
detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(
    url=single_face_image_url,
    detectionModel='detection_02',
    return_face_attributes=face_attributes)
if not detected_faces:
    raise Exception('No face detected from image {}'.format(single_image_name))

for face in detected_faces:
    emotionObject = face.face_attributes.emotion.as_dict()
    print(', '.join([f'{v:.0%} {k}' for k, v in emotionObject.items(
    ) if k != 'additional_properties']))
```

Answered by Jim Xu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283093/11725869)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
d = {'additional_properties': {}, 'anger': 0.001, 'contempt': 0.002, 'disgust': 0.0, 'fear': 0.0, 'happiness': 0.542, 'neutral': 0.455, 'sadness': 0.0, 'surprise': 0.0}
```

This formats the emotion keys as the desired string:

```py
print(', '.join([f'{v:.0%} {k}' for k,v in d.items() if k != 'additional_properties']))
```

Output:

```
0% anger, 0% contempt, 0% disgust, 0% fear, 54% happiness, 46% neutral, 0% sadness, 0% surprise
```

Comment: What makes you think the `Emotion` class has an `items()` method like dictionaries do?

Comment: it does not, that is why I get the error `'Emotion' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: @Barmar I don't.  I don't have the library, but given `d` above, it works. 
 Could always do `d = ast.literal_eval(str(face.face_attributes.emotion)) ` since it prints as a dictionary :^)

Comment: could it be possible for you to update your answer please? @MarkTolonen